# GeoServer WFS 502 error

Tags: geoserver, wfs

GeoServer 2.8.2
I am getting the following error when trying to update our WFS MapInfo asset data stored in a Pitney Bowes Confirm database. This error only effects one dataset. there are several other datasets that update from the same database without any problem.

Sending HTTP 'GET' request to 'http://mapserver---------, waiting for response ...
Received HTTP response header: 'HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error'
Received HTTP response header: 'Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 22:54:00 GMT'
Received HTTP response header: 'Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)'
Received HTTP response header: 'Content-Length: 469'
Received HTTP response header: 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
HTTP transfer summary - download-size: '469 bytes', download-time: '300.11 seconds', url: 'http://mapserver----------
**XML Parser error: 'Error in input dataset:**'http://mapserver---------
**line:1 column:50 message:whitespace expected'**
**The XML Module halted on error,** see the logfile for details
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
Translation FAILED with 3 error(s) and 0 warning(s) (0 feature(s) output)
FME Session Duration: 5 minutes 1.0 seconds. (CPU: 0.3s user, 0.7s system)
END - ProcessID: 6244, peak process memory usage: 84052 kB, current process memory usage: 81936 kB
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
Program Terminating
Translation FAILED.

Am I right to assume the error is on the database server and not a problem with the GeoServer?

I don't know where to find the file that the error refers to: **line:1 column:50 message:whitespace expected'**

Comment: Errors do seem to come outside GeoServer. There is some FME session running and it should have written the reason of the failure into a log file. Try to find that log.

Comment: that error refers to the response sent back you GeoServer and is probably an indication that it has generated an error message and not an XML file